# sesquilinearform only small on diagonal

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sesquilinear-forms

We are given a sesquilinear form $a \colon V \times V \to \mathbb{C}$ on a complex Hilbert space $V$. We know that $a$ is bounded and $a(u,u)$ is small for all $u \in V$. Can we make any assertions on the size of $a(u,v)$, that is to say, can we (under further assumptions?) make assertions about the size of a sesquilinear form if it it small on the diagonal in $V\times V$?

Comment: By "bounded" do you mean that $|a(u,u)|\leq C\lVert u\rVert^2$ where $C>0$ is a constant? Otherwise consider $a(10^nu,10^nu)=10^{2n}a(u,u)\to\infty$ (unless $a=0$).

Comment: By bounded I mean $|a(u,v)| \leq C \| u \| \| v \|$. And the question is, if I can quantify the constant $C$ by the optimal constant $c$ in the case $u=v$.

Comment: The [polarization formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1931752/472818) gives $|a(u,v)|\leq c(\lVert u\rVert^2+\lVert v\rVert^2)$, but that's not what we want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption $|a(u,u)|\leq c\lVert u\rVert^2$ for all $u$, where $c>0$ is a constant.

Considering the [polarization formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1931752/472818), we have

$$|a(u,v)|\leq\frac14\Big(c\lVert u+v\rVert^2+c\lVert u-v\rVert^2+c\lVert u+iv\rVert^2+c\lVert u-iv\rVert^2\Big)$$
$$=\frac14\Big(c\big(\lVert u\rVert^2+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2\big)+c\big(\lVert u\rVert^2-\langle u,v\rangle-\langle v,u\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2\big)\qquad \\ \qquad+c\big(\lVert u\rVert^2+\langle u,iv\rangle+\langle iv,u\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2\big)+c\big(\lVert u\rVert^2-\langle u,iv\rangle-\langle iv,u\rangle+\lVert v\rVert^2\big)\Big)$$
$$=\frac14\Big(4c\lVert u\rVert^2+4c\lVert v\rVert^2\Big)$$
$$=c\Big(\lVert u\rVert^2+\lVert v\rVert^2\Big).$$

Now, given any $u,v\neq0$, let $u'=\sqrt\frac{\lVert v\rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}u$ and $v'=\sqrt\frac{\lVert u\rVert}{\lVert v\rVert}v$, so that $\lVert u'\rVert=\lVert v'\rVert=\sqrt{\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert}$, and

$$|a(u,v)|=|a(u',v')|\leq c\Big(\lVert u'\rVert^2+\lVert v'\rVert^2\Big)=2c\lVert u\rVert\lVert v\rVert.$$

Comment: That's the optimal constant (+). For example if $a(u,v)=2u_1\overline{v_2}$ on $\mathbb{C}^2,$ then $c=1$ but $a(e_1,e_2)=2\|e_1\|\,\|e_2\|$ for $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1).$

Comment: And the optimal constant for symmetric bilinear forms is $1$, which follows from an analogous analysis of the simpler polarization formula $$a(u,v)=\frac14\Big(a(u+v,u+v)-a(u-v,u-v)\Big).$$

Comment: Or for self-adjoint sesqulinar form, i.e. $a(u,v)=\overline{a(v,u)}.$

Comment: What formula would you use in that case?

Comment: Okay, I found it in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/924505/472818).